# .net assembly embedded resource vs traditional file vs database?

Tags: c#, .net, web

I have a C# web service that validates and transforms xml and It need a series of xslt and xsd files to do it. 20 xsd and 20 xslt files.

We plan to deploy this web service to more or less 1500 users.

To get the best perfomance, what is the best alternative to access these files: assembly embeddeded resources or traditional filesystem or a sql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using file access is fine especially if they are already stored as files. Look into how you can cache what you read from the files to really improve your performance.

So for example if you can cache only 5 files at once (depends on file size etc) then look at how you can cache the 5 most used files and only read from the files if there is a cache miss.